# Check if a Button is Tapped in UITestCase

Tags: ios, xcode7, coded-ui-tests

The UI has a simple Button which returns a XCUIElement, on printing the value it is returning an empty @"" string before and after tapping.

As per the apple WWDC conference video this was working, i tried it on both Swift and objective c.

```
id valuebeforeTap = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init].buttons[@"Button"].value;

NSLog(@"value before Tap =%@",valuebeforeTap);

[[[XCUIApplication alloc] init].buttons[@"Button"] tap];

id valueaftertap = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init].buttons[@"Button"].value;

NSLog(@"value before Tap =%@",valueaftertap);
```

Any means how i can validate this test case?